# How can I format a date object from JS inside PHP to a SQL timestamp format including the timezone?

Tags: php, date

I'm currently receiving the following date object from JS inside PHP via a `POST` request:

```
Tue Feb 25 2020 22:31:03 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
```

How can I format this now to the SQL timestamp format `Y-m-d H:i:s` including the given timezone at the end?

I've tried this:

```
date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 'Tue Feb 25 2020 22:31:03 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)' )
```

But this causes an error:

> date() expects parameter 2 to be int, string given

I've already searched on SO but I can only find questions about timestamps.

Comment: The first code line looks like `toString()` output of a Date object. Which means you can use `getTime()` to turn it into seconds. These can be passed into `time` in `int` format, i.e. `intval($_POST['seconds'])` or what have you.

Comment: @ChrisG Do you mean getTime() inside JS and then format it how I want it? If yes, this turns out in PHP when passing `getTime()` from JS in this code `date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', intval( $created_at ) )`: `52122-09-21 23:28:27` ($created_at is my unchanged value from the request)

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` returns a huge integer, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. edit: the number of milliseconds apparently, so divide by 1000 first.

Comment: I've found something about the timestamp. It's different between JS and PHP. So I did this `date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $created_at / 1000 )` Output: `2020-02-25 21:47:52` Problem: The timezone is not current. How can I respect the timezone given by the browser now?

Comment: You don't. The time you see is "one hour behind" because it's UTC. Creating a `Date()` from it in the browser and displaying it will automatically use local time again. Never, ever, store timestamps in local time. Always use UTC, that way it's universal.

Comment: But when I set my field in my DB to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default and create a new entry, the local timezone is used: `2020-02-25 22:57:39`. In PHP it's `2020-02-25 21:57:39`. So this is the actual problem for me. And by the way I can't set the timestamp by default because there is a time gap between the browser and the request / saving. So I need to take the exact browser timestamp.

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question. If you always need to use browser time, you can't use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` anyway, right? So always pass the seconds over and store those.

Comment: Also see here: https://javorszky.co.uk/2016/06/06/today-i-learned-about-mysql-and-timezones/

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will take a string and give you what `date` needs. Try:

```
date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Tue Feb 25 2020 22:31:03 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)') );
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this because turning a Date object into a textual representation only to parse it back into a date object is obviously bad practice.

Comment: This turns out: 1970-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @ChrisG, I agree, it's bad practice, but it's "technically" the answer to the question :) A better approach would be to convert the date to time in JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime and use that in PHP. That will also save some bits in network payload size.

Comment: Fair enough, but the answer to an xy problem should never ignore the fact that it's an xy problem. Other people might find this question, and the bad practice propagates. Just like with w3schools.

Comment: Totally agree, kudos!! @Chris